# Click() method not supporting on .Net Application on IE using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

source code:

```
<div class="dropdown-toggle" id="clientBtnDropDown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" onclick="ga(&quot;send&quot;, {&quot;hitType&quot; : &quot;event&quot;,&quot;eventCategory&quot; : &quot;Client button&quot;,&quot;eventAction&quot; : &quot;click&quot;,&quot;eventLabel&quot; : &quot;Client access&quot;});ga(&quot;t2.send&quot;, {&quot;hitType&quot; : &quot;event&quot;,&quot;eventCategory&quot; : &quot;Client button&quot;,&quot;eventAction&quot; : &quot;click&quot;,&quot;eventLabel&quot; : &quot;Client access&quot;});"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Client access</a></div>
```

Work flow: when i click on a linkbutton(Client access), it will popup one window ,which is a login window(Frame) where we can enter user id and password.

but whenever i try to perform through selenium i used to get error message to click on the button.

Code i have written:

> driver.findElement(By.Id("clientBtnDropDown")).Click()

here it is throwing error like doesn't support click method.

am i doing anything wrong or is there any alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

You need `driver.FindElement`. Note the capital letter in 'Find'.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Id is the DIV tags. where as your actual anchor tag is inside the Div tag. I would suggest you to use the Xpath or CSS selector and find the directly  for 'Client access' element.

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(.btn.btn-primary)).Click();
```

Comment: No luck,giving error "An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException' occurred in WebDriver.dll" if i use CSSlocator. i have tried in 2 ways driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".btn.btn-primary")).Click();
 driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div#clientBtnDropDown > a")).Click();

Comment: Okay, try Xpath but directly on your button

Comment: Sorry dude for suggesting multiple items. Im trying to figure out the solution for yours. You might have already tried By.LinkText or By.PartialText. If not give a try as it is an Anchor tag only. Before doing all these make sure your element is visible on the page and enabled